# How do I echo a mysql result in UTF-8 into my page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm listing the customers names on my webpage with PHP retrieving data from MySql, but some of them are called José, João, but when I echo the result on the page, it shows Jos� and Jo�o.
The collations of the tables are all on utf8_general_ci what can I possibly be doing wrong??

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a browser display issue. Try adding the following line between the head tags of your html document.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

This should solve the problem. If not, leave a comment And I'll help you resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Your page source code should also be utf-8 encoded, to display UTF8 encoded characters, otherwise your browser tries to apply character encoding from http header to you strings.

Answer (score 0):

use

`echo utf8_encode($yourstring);`

but, also is recommended to set in html

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

and consider to create database with utf-8 encoding and collation spanish or whatever it have this kind of characters